# How to get the combinations of a group from a column in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df with the column keyword:

```
Keyword   
A          
A          
A         
B
B
B
C
C
D
D
```

i am dividing into groups using the following code

```
df_unique = df.groupby('Keyword').nunique()
```

But i want the combinations of the unique  groups from the column.

### o/p:

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with list comprehension and `f-string`s for join tuples:

```
from  itertools import combinations
L = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in combinations(df['Keyword'].unique(), 2)]
print (L)
['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'comb':L})
print (df1)
  comb
0   AB
1   AC
2   AD
3   BC
4   BD
5   CD
```

For 2 columns:

```
from  itertools import combinations
L1 = list(combinations(df['Keyword'].unique(), 2))
print (L1)
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L1, columns=['comb1','comb2'])
print (df1)
  comb1 comb2
0     A     B
1     A     C
2     A     D
3     B     C
4     B     D
5     C     D
```